# How to make a function an argument for a custom made function?

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I created a function to add significance stars next to values that are statistically significant. I made this function because I am creating tables for different test statistics. What I want to do with this code is create an argument in the custom made function that will change the test statistic being used. For example, instead of a binomial, I might want to use a fisher exact test, so I would want to enter test_star_loop(data=data, test = fisher.test) to execute the Fisher test. Is there a simple way to do this without using if and else statements?

Here is the code I wrote. It creates the stars I want for the binomial test, but I am not sure how to make it so I can apply it to different test statistics.

```
test_star_loop <- function(data){
  # convert table to dataframe
  data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, data)

  # vector to store stars for each column in
  stars <- rep("", ncol(data))
  # iteratre over each column
  for (col in seq_along(data)) {
  # do binomial test on top row

  # number of times subjects avoid =ed information
  n_success <- round((data[1, col]/100)*data[2, col], 0)
  
  binom_result <- binom.test(x = n_success, n = data[2, col], p = 0)
  # check if p-value < 0.01
  if (binom_result$p.value < 0.01) {
      stars[col] <- "***"
    }
  # check if p-value  < 0.05
  else if (binom_result$p.value < 0.05) {
      stars[col] <- "**"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sure: if your formal arguments include `test=fisher.test`, then in your function, instead of calling `fisher.test(x, alternative="greater")`, you would call `test(x, alternative="greater")`. Inside the function, `test` ***is*** `fisher.test`. Your problem is not using `test` as a function for testing (since it is a function), it's how you use it internally, and if each test the user might provide use the same arguments (and for the same purposes).

Comment: If you are just adding stars, I recommend using {rstatix} package. See [this page](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/rstatix/reference/p_value.html) and it could help add stars to your stats.

Comment: aside: `vector("character", n)` is an alternative to `rep("", n)`

Comment: Thanks for the response @r2evans. Is there a way to do it, such that the parameters of the function can be adjust. I mentioned this because the arguments for binomial test are different than for fisher exact.